# Get the player front position at specific distance

Tags: unity, c#

The simple way to get player front position at specific distance

```
     Vectro3 forward = player.transform.forward * distance;
     Vector3 newPlayerFronPosition= player.transform.position + new Vector3(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z);
     newPlayerFronPosition= new Vector3(newPlayerFronPosition.x, newPlayerFronPosition.y - 4f, newPlayerFronPosition.z);
     navigationCanvas.transform.position = newPlayerFronPosition;
     navigationCanvas.transform.rotation = camRotationToWatch.transform.rotation;
```

its actually working fine but the problem is as my player move up or down the navCanvas become appear ver near to my player. How to mainitain spcific distance all the time.?? that no matter player look above or down the navcanvas display at specfic distance.(position)

```
disatnceUICam = Vector3.Distance(newPlayerFronPosition, player.transform.position);
```

I also logged the distance and surprisingly it the distance is changing when i am moving up or down. its changing from 6 to 12 as i am looking up to down.

Comment: Are you sure the distance variable doesn't change?

Comment: @Bálint yes man i am sure i didn't change it and i also checked it in inspector. it remains constant